# What happens to radians in this calculation?

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, rotation, power

[image]

I rewrite N as kg m s^-2 and try to get Pmax, which is in Watts to kg m^2 s^-3 but when I do so I am left with an rad^2.

Comment: This may be relevant - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803955/. Basically radian is ratio of length of arc to radius so the units cancel out.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252288/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @JarosławKomar you mean 4pi becomes a unitless number?

Comment: You have probably already encountered this in the formula for uniform circular motion, $v=\omega r$.

Comment: $4\pi$ is dimensionless