# Units of angular frequency in a simple harmonic oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, frequency, units, dimensional-analysis, angular-velocity

The equation of a simple harmonic motion can be
$x=A \cos(\omega t)$.

$\omega$ therefore has units of $radians/sec$.

I was solving some problems when I found a statement on my notes

> $x=\left(1+\omega_{0} t\right)(e)^{-\omega_{0} t}$

with the variables having the usual meanings. I believe the statement is absurd because the left hand side has dimensions of distance and the right hand side has of radians (as $\omega t $ is in radians ) not to mention that the exponential has units of radians as well.

Could anyone please point out my mistake. I'd be glad even for a hint. Thank you.

Comment: I believe you copied the note incorrectly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's primarily about units and algebra, not a broad physics concept outside of the mathematical mistake. It is also most likely related to a copying error.

Comment: Thank you dear Bill, I downloaded the note from the University and found the same thing. I checked it over and again for an hour and only then posted here. For me it was more probable that I'm at error then the teacher that's why I posted because I thought maybe there is something that I'm failing to understand. :)

Comment: Ok. The note is incomplete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are units of angle really dimensionless?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252288/are-units-of-angle-really-dimensionless)

Comment: In the last equation, $x$ is dimensionless.  The units are consistent - You're wrong about your assertion that anything in that equation has units of length.  Some context would probably make this clear.

Answer (score 2):

"Radians" aren't really units. E.g. $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (or $90^{\circ}$) is just a dimensionless number. That's why in physics/math we prefer "radians" to degrees.

$\mathrm{radians/second}$ is thus really $\mathrm{s^{-1}}$, in $\text{SI}$ units.

Your expression:

$$x=\left(1+\omega_{0} t\right)e^{-\omega_{0} t}$$

cannot refer to a distance, unless its RHS is multiplied by some factor $A$ with units $\mathrm{m}$.

Comment: Thank you dear Gert, but Wikipedia says"The radian, denoted by the symbol ${\displaystyle {\text{rad}}}$ is the SI unit for measuring angles, and is the standard unit of angular measure used in many areas of mathematics".

Comment: radian = distance / distance. Its dimensionless

Comment: Well, Wiki is wrong on this. That's not the first time either! It's like claiming the number $5$ has SI units: not true.

Comment: NIST also calls radian an SI unit, but it's a *dimensionless* unit.  So you're both right. https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/SIdiagram.html