# Units of Linear Speed in a Circular Motion

Tags: kinematics, dimensional-analysis, speed, si-units

During Uniform Circular Motion, the linear speed of the particle is defined as the radius times the angular speed.
$$ v = r\omega $$
The units of linear speed is meters/second (m/s). But the units of $ r\omega $ is $  m\frac {rad}{s} $. How is this possible? And why does the unit "radian" cancel out?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I teach students circular motion right now and I'll mention it for them too. If you were confused, they also can be puzzled :)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252288/123208

Comment: Thank you and Welcome!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rad is a dimensionless unit. It is defined as such an angle that it intercepts an arc on a circle with the length equal to the radius of a circle. Angle in radians is the length of an arc over radius, therefore meter over meter: $\theta = L_{arc}/R$. They are dimensionless in nature and people write "rad" simply for convenience.

Comment: I write radians or rad to indicate that I'm talking about an angle.